# Hook a C function

Tags: c, macos, hook, core-audio, function-interposition

I want to hook the function `AudioUnitInitialize` to grab the Audio Unit of an application by injecting a bundle at the application start.
I found an example (http://pastie.org/1882125) but it uses the function `MSHookFunction` to replace the function names. The problem is that I want to replace the functions on Mac OS X, not on iOS.
Is there another way to hook C functions?

Comment: MobileSubstrate is open source so you could just look at how saurik did it in MSHookFunction

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't CydiaSubstrate.framework available on OS X too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [look closely](http://gitweb.saurik.com/substrate.git/blob/HEAD:/Hooker.cpp), you can find out that MobileSubstrate runs on OS X as well.

Comment: Now I got everything with this tutorial (http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-install-thoes-under-xcode-44.html). My problem is that when I hook the method `AudioUnitInitialize`, I can't use the parameter `inUnit`. What's the problem here? The application crashes then.

Comment: @qPaul I don't know, but that's certainly not something that should make you unaccept my answer - I answered your question. Ask a new question, because you **do have** a new one - about using the API.